# Chinese transit visa for Indian citizen

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, china, china-eastern

I am an Indian citizen living in Canada on a work permit. I am planning to take a China eastern flight for my next trip to India. The itinerary is as follows :

1. Vancouver International Airport YVR -> Nanjing Lukou International Airport NKG

Arrival at 14:30, layover 2 hours.

2. Vancouver International Airport YVR -> Kunming Changshui International Airport KMG

Arrival at 16:30, layover 4 hour 10 minutes.

3. Kunming Changshui International Airport KMG -> Netaji Subhash Chandra Bose International Airport CCU.

It seems like under TWOV rules, since my transit is less than 24 hours, I am eligible for a visa free transit. Is that right?

Also is there any here who had experience with this route. Is a 2 hour layover sufficient to catch a connecting flight NKG? I am not planning to have any checked bags.

The itinerary is a single ticket, but my worry is that if my flight from NKG gets delayed or I miss the connection and the next flight is in more than 24 hours, I am not eligible for visa free transit anymore. What happens in this case?